# Laravel track job chain start and finish

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have created a chain of deployment jobs in Laravel following the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#job-chaining

From the docs (similar to my code):

```
ProcessPodcast::withChain([
    new OptimizePodcast,
    new ReleasePodcast
])->dispatch();
```

Is there any way to track whether the job chain has started and finished completely?

I guess a possibility would to always start the chain with a `beforeDeployment` job and a `afterDeployment` job. Since the chain gets broken when an error happens and the `afterDeployment` will not be reached, this seems feasible.

Any thoughts on taking this approach or is there something easier to be done?

I guess my approach would allow me to set a listener like so:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#job-events

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if I was implementing this – I'd have an event fire upon success `PodcastWasReleased` which notified me, but I'd hook into the `Queue::failing()` listener (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#failed-job-events) to again, fire an event `PodcastFailedToRelease`.

You could pass the job which failed into the event to give a concise idea as to what happened, as well as the stack trace available in the JobFailed object.

Does that help? Maybe it'll at least set you on a different path.

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Currently I have added 2 Jobs on the chain to signify the start and end of a delpoyment chain. If I were to fire an event upon `PodcastWasReleased` it would mean this would always be the start of a deployment and it would create very tight coupling. Since I can have multiple deployments chains with different Jobs in them this would not be desirable(PodcastWasReleased might not even be in there). I have simply created a method which accepts all the jobs `in between` the starting and ending Job.

Comment: I see, that sounds actually really interesting. Would you mind DMing me the code over here? I'd love to see that.